# How do Russians view the Kurds?

Tags: russian-federation, public-opinion, turkey, kurdistan

Are there any polls or research on how the Russian populace views the Kurds (in general, or those in Turkey specifically)?

Answer (score 5):

It's unlikely. If "no opinion" were an option, I would expect that to be the dominant answer. As far as I can tell, no major poll along these lines has been taken in the US either. If Russians are any more more opinionated on Kurdish issues, they are also subject to less extensive polling.

While not directly related to the question, there is a political analysis on the National Interest website that goes into some detail about [the history of Russian-Kurdish relations](http://nationalinterest.org/feature/vladimir-putin-godfather-kurdistan-15358?page=show) since the nineteenth century. It may also be interesting to note that [Zelimkhan Mutsoev](https://www.forbes.com/profile/zelimkhan-mutsoev/), a very wealthy Russian MP in Putin's own party, is from a Yazidi Kurdish background. The ethnic [Kurdish population in Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurds_in_Russia) was about 63,000 in the 2010 census.